# Show year from type DateTime vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

I have this code.

```
Dim dteEnd As New Date
dteEnd = New DateTime(CInt(ddlIntervallStart.SelectedValue), 12, 31)
```

How can I show only year in format DateTime. I need same type because I work with Oracle and database must have format Date.

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("P_DATUM_BIS", OracleDbType.Date).Value = dteEnd
```

Comment: You just want to pass the year to the database? `dteEnd.Year` will show only the year.  But then the SQL Type is a full Date, not just a year, so it's not clear if that's what you really want? Do you want to pass the date part without a time part?

Comment: @ADyson yes, I have in Drop Down List sorting - year, quarter and month. Now all of this show next format dd.mm.yyyy. But I must make for year yyyy format, for quarter Q1-yyyy and for month mm-yyyy. I have no idea how to do this

Comment: I doubt that `OracleDbType.Date` will accept " Q1-yyyy" or "mm-yyyy" formats. It will accept whole dates, with or without a time component.

Comment: @ADyson I thought about that, the only way out is to change the format to string

Comment: If you need to store imprecise dates like this, then you could store it as a raw string, as long as your application is careful to validate what is being inserted is in a format that is acceptable. You could also store a separate field which indicates what type of string it is (i.e. indicates a quarter, or a year, or a month) so you can easily parse it out again when you come to read the data later.

Comment: The logical type of a "year" is integer.  If the dbase requires you to specify a date then surely it will be happy with January 1st of that year.  And for a quarter it will be, say, March 1st.  And for a month it will be, say, November 1st.  Use the DateTime(year, month, day) constructor.  Do keep in mind that these are *ranges*, you'd normally expect the query to take a begin and end date.  Talk to whomever created the query to find out what was intended.